# SCNAction refresh rate

Tags: apple-watch, scenekit

I'm currently trying to develop a little game on Apple Watch using SceneKit.

This is a simple 2D game, with geometric shapes I tesselate.

Here is my problem. I use SCNAction to move my objects across the scene, and I don't know why, but even if the SCNScene showStatistics show me the scene runs at 60 FPS and I can see that the CPU does very little, every SCNAction is updated every half-second or so.

It's very annoying because my animations aren't smooth at all and it hurts gameplay.

Does anyone already had had this kind of problem? I've spent too much time trying to find where something went wrong and I can't find it. Is there some kind of refresh rate property on SCNAction?

Thank you in advance for the time you'll give to my case. :)

Comment: Try setting SCNView.playing to YES.